# Characterization of a vector space over an associative division ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $M$ be a (left) module over an associative division ring $R$.
Then it has the following properties.

1) For every submodule $N$ of $M$, there exists a submodule $L$ such that $M = N + L$
and $M \cap L = 0$.

2) Every finitely generated submodule has a composition series.

Now let $M \neq 0$ be a (left) **faithful** module over an associative ring $R$ with unity 1.
Suppose $M$ satisfies the above conditions.
Is $R$ necessarily a division ring?

**EDIT** Related question:[Module over a ring which satisfies Whitehead's axioms of projective geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/939340/module-over-a-ring-which-satisfies-whiteheads-axioms-of-projective-geometry)

Comment: Is the condition you actually want that every module $M$ has the above properties?

Comment: If so, I think this is true iff $R$ is semisimple. In particular $R$ can be a matrix ring over a division ring.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan No. I'm asking if an existence of one such $M$ implies that $R$ is a division ring.
However, as you wrote, this is not the case.
I'm looking for sufficient conditions on $M$ for $R$ to be a division ring.

Comment: There are no such conditions which can be stated purely internally to the category of modules. The reason is that any such conditions will be Morita invariant, but being a division ring is not a Morita invariant property. More concretely, categorical statements about modules can't distinguish division rings from matrix algebras over division rings, which have the same categories of modules.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: May I humbly suggest that you promote that to an answer?

Comment: Also notice that condition $1$ just says "$M$ is semisimple," and then all submodules are semisimple, including the finitely generated ones. Finitely generated semisimple modules of course have composition series. So what I'm getting at is that 1$\implies$2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If $R$ is the ring of $2\times2$ matrices over a field $K$ and $M=K^2$ is the left $R$-module of column vectors, then

- $M$ has no non-trivial submodules, so conditions 1)+2) are vacuously true, and
- $R$ is the ring of endomorphisms of $M$ as a $K$-module, so it is a faithful module, but
- $R$ is not a division ring.

Answer (score 0):

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}$ so that $R$-modules are abelian groups and submodules are subgroups.  Let $M$ be a cyclic group of prime order.  Then $M$ is simple, so 1) is satisfied, and every finite group has a composition series, so 2) is satisfied.  However, $R$ is not a division ring.

Comment: If the version of the question you're answering is "suppose every $M$ satisfies..." then I don't see what you're doing. Take $M = \mathbb{Z}$. It's finitely generated but it doesn't have a composition series because it doesn't have a maximal submodule.

Comment: So 2) fails. And 1) also fails because e.g. in $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$ the submodule $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ fails to have a complement.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I'm answering the question as written, but you're probably right to suggest that the question is meant to be "suppose every $R$-module $M$ satisfies...," in which case this answer is incorrect.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to impose the obvious condition that $M$ is a **faithful** module over $R$.