# Module over a ring which satisfies Whitehead's axioms of projective geometry

Tags: abstract-algebra, projective-geometry, axioms

I asked this question([Characterization of a vector space over an associative division ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/938520/characterization-of-a-vector-space-over-an-associative-division-ring)).
It was pointed out that the answer was negative.
So I reconsidered the problem and have come up with the present one.

According to Wikipedia(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_geometry#Axioms_of_projective_geometry), the axioms of projective geometry due to A. N. Whitehead are:

G1: Every line contains at least 3 points

G2: Every two points, A and B, lie on a unique line, AB.

G3: If lines AB and CD intersect, then so do lines AC and BD
 (where it is assumed that A and D are distinct from B and C).

Now let $V$ be a vector space over a field $K$.
We denote by $P(V)$ the set of one-dimensional subspaces of $V$.
If $V$ is finite dimensional, this is the usual definition of a projective space over $K$.
We say a two-dimensional subspace of $V$ a line of $P(V)$.
Then points and lines of $P(V)$ satisfy the above axioms(see
[Whitehead's axioms of projective geometry and a vector space over a field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/938707/whiteheads-axioms-of-projective-geometry-and-a-vector-space-over-a-field))

Conversely let $M$ be a *faithful* left module over an associative ring $R$ with unity.
Suppose $M$ satisfies the following conditions.

1) It has a composition series.

2) For every submodule $N$ of $M$, there exists a submodule $L$ such that $M = N + L$
and $N \cap L = 0$.

Then every submodule $N$ has a composition series.
We call its length the dimension of $N$ and denote it by dim $N$.
Let $P(M)$ be the set of one-dimensional submodules of $M$.
An element of $P(M)$ is called a point.
We say a two-dimensional submodule a line of $P(M)$.
Then it is clear that $P(M)$ satisfies Axiom G2.
It is not difficult to see that it also satisfies Axiom G3(see the answer to aforementioned question).

Now we add the following conditions on $M$.

3) $P(M)$ satisfies Axiom G1.

4) dim $M \ge 3$.

If $M$ satisfies the conditions 1), 2), 3), 4) is $R$ necessarily a division ring?

Answer (score 1):

For a division ring $D$, let the matrix ring $M_3(D)=M=R$.

Now you can see the answer is **no**:

- $M$ is obviously faithful and has composition length $3$.
- It is a semisimple module since $R$ is a semisimple ring
- Any dimension $2$ module over $R$ looks like $S\oplus S$ where $S$ is (the unique) dimension $1$ module for $R$. This module has at least three distinct dimension $1$ submodules: $S\oplus \{0\}$, $\{0\}\oplus S$, and $\{(s,s)\mid s\in S\}$.

Comment: Now that I follow the link in the question, I've noticed that this straightforward solution is just a minor modification of the solution you got there. I think you should think a little more before you post! You can probably get it yourself... :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually checked to see if this works but it seems that the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ might satisfy these conditions.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot the obvious condition that $M$ is a *faithful* module over $R$.

Comment: Again, I haven't checked this, but what if you take the same module and consider it as a $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[t]$-module, where $t$ acts trivially on all elements?

Comment: Then it is not a faithful module over $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[t]$.

Comment: Oops, just realized that